# C++ equivalent function to matlab quantize and quantizer?

Tags: c++, matlab, floating-point

In MATLAB it is fairly straightforward to quantize data using the quantizer() and quantize() functions.

For example in matlab you can create the following quantizer object, to generate a 6 bit floating point object with a 4-bit exponent:

```
q = quantizer('float',[6 4], 'Roundmode','convergent');
```

Then you can quantize a value as follows

```
quantize(q,3.4)
ans = 3
```

Is there an equivalent way to do this in C++?

I want to set the mantissa width, exponent width, and use round to nearest.

Comment: If you have MATLAB Coder product you can generate code for the quantize function and use the generated C code.

Comment: Don't seem to have that product